# How to have different sample rates for different endpoints with Datadog

Tags: python, datadog

Datadog can be configured to have different sample rates for different services via the `DD_TRACE_SAMPLING_RULES` environment variable. But how could we have different sample rates for different endpoints within a service?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to drop traces with a certain tag at the agent level. (Set `DD_APM_FILTER_TAGS_REJECT` at the agent to reject a certain tag value.) Then randomly add that tag within the endpoints.

E.g.

```py
import random
from ddtrace import tracer


def sample_traces(sample_rate=1.0):
  span = tracer.current_root_span()
  # keep sample_rate*100% of traces
  if random.random() >= sample_rate:
      # assuming we've set reject_span:TRUE in DD_APM_FILTER_TAGS_REJECT
      span.set_tag("reject_span", "TRUE")


def endpoint_to_sample(...):
  # sample 50% of calls
  sample_traces(0.5)
  ...
```

Comment: Instead of dropping traces at the agent, this can be done from the Python library: https://ddtrace.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced_usage.html#trace-filtering